# question about combinatorics but i've never played poker.

Tags: probability, poker

I have a questions about combinatorics.

my question : You are playing a version of poker where you can see three of your cards and three of your
opponents. She has 6♣, 8♣, 10♣ and you have A♦, A♣, A♠. What is the probability that you will win? (both have 5 cards)

I'm not familiar with poker. I found the rules but i'm confused since i have no experience.

Could you help me??

Comment: This is a cruel question to ask someone who has never played poker... I'm sorry.  The end result is that you will win *unless* your opponent either completes her flush (by getting two more clubs), completes her straight (by getting a 7 and a 9) *unless* you happened to get a fourth Ace or a side pair *unless* she happened to have gotten a straight flush...

Comment: @JMoravitz I got inspiration thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranking of the possible hands
Straight flush-your opponent draws 7C, 9C
Four of a kind-you draw the fourth ace
Full house-you draw a pair
Flush-your opponent draws two clubs that are not 7,9
Straight-your opponent draws a 7 and a 9, not both clubs
Three of a kind-neither of you improve
For the complete list, which you do not need here, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)

As for calculating the respective probabilities... this becomes quite tedious.

The probability that your opponent completes her straight flush and draws both $7\clubsuit$ and $9\clubsuit$ will be $\dfrac{1}{\binom{46}{2}}$

The probability that your opponent did not complete her straight flush and that you did complete your four-of-a-kind will be $\dfrac{2}{46}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{45}{2}-1}{\binom{45}{2}}$

The probability that your opponent did not complete her straight flush and that you did complete your full house will be $\dfrac{2\cdot 3}{\binom{46}{2}}+\left(\dfrac{5\cdot 3 + 7\cdot \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{46}{2}}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\binom{44}{2}-1}{\binom{44}{2}}$

The probability that your opponent did complete a straight but not a straight flush while you did not complete your four-of-a-kind or full house will be $\dfrac{4^2-1}{\binom{46}{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{7}{2}\cdot 4^2+7\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 + \binom{5}{2}\cdot 3^2}{\binom{44}{2}}$

The probability that your opponent did complete a flush but not a straight flush while you did not complete your four-of-a-kind or full house will be $\dfrac{\binom{9}{2}-1}{\binom{46}{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{7}{2}\cdot 4^2+7\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 + \binom{5}{2}\cdot 3^2}{\binom{44}{2}}$

Finally, all remaining probability will correspond to you winning with a three-of-a-kind of Aces, the probability of this occurring will be $1$ minus all of the previously mentioned probabilities.

The probability of you winning will then be the sum of the second, third, and fifth of the above probabilities while the probability of your opponent winning will be the sum of the remaining probabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Hence to win, i have 1 case among 4 of a kind , full house and 3 of a kind. Is it right?

Comment: Those are the hands that might win, but whether they win depends on what your opponent has.  Once you each draw two more cards, you look down the list.  The first one you find that is satisfied wins, so if she gets 7C,9C she wins regardless of what you get.  If she gets a flush, you need either four of a kind or a full house to beat it.

Comment: That of course only describes how to *interpret* a particular way in which the cards continue to be drawn.  To answer the question of *probabilities*, more attention and careful case-work needs to be applied.

Comment: The calculation above for winning with four of a kind is not correct.  She draws two cards and we know the chance they are not 7C, 9C is $1-\frac 1{46 \choose 2}$.  That means the chance she drew an ace is increased a bit, so your chance of drawing an ace is decreased.  The probabilities are not independent.  I also do not understand all the factors of $2$.  If we were told your opponent did not draw an ace, your chance of getting one would be $\frac 2{44}$ but we are not told that.  Your chance of winning with four of a kind is close to $\frac 2{44}-\frac 2{46\cdot 45}$

Comment: The probability she does not get her straight-flush and that you do get your four-of-a-kind, let us begin by dealing with the four of a kind.  Pick "which of the two cards" dealt to you was the remaining ace and the probability of it having been an ace.  You can't have them both be an ace, so the probability of you having gotten your fourth ace is $\frac{2}{46}$.  Ignore what the fifth card you receive is, and "now deal the remaining cards to your opponent."  Given that you were dealt your fourth ace, she misses her straight flush so long as she misses getting both required cards...will adjust

Comment: Hmm,, so disgusting... first of all thank you so mucu both...in fifth case, you said 'my opponent complete flush and i did not complete full house or 4 of a kind'. then in this case not winning me but winning oppenent, right?

Comment: That is correct.  You would just have three of a kind, which a flush (and a straight) beats.

Comment: thank you i analyze your comment long ago but i have some incomprehensible part... i need to study more now.. very very thank you.. take care of your health since corona virus..

Comment: I think it is easier to understand, and simpler to calculate, if we first count the number of ways the opponent can win (unfavorable outcomes), subtract that from the total number of outcomes to get number of favorable outcomes, then divide by the total to get the probability of winning.